# Convert array of objects to JSON

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of Objects

```
[{"a":{"name":"abc","age":2}},
{"b":{"name":"xyz","age":3}},
{"c":{"name":"pqr","age":4}}]
```

I need to convert this to

```
[{"name":"abc","age":2},
{"name":"xyz","age":3},
{"name":"pqr","age":4}]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service and expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1823841). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @SandipND it does'nt work with JSON.stringify()

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: @SandipND : It worked when I added JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 6):

Simply use `map` and `Object.values`

```
var output = arr.map( s => Object.values(s)[0] );
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
    "a": {
      "name": "abc",
      "age": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "b": {
      "name": "xyz",
      "age": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "c": {
      "name": "pqr",
      "age": 4
    }
  }
];
var output = arr.map( s => Object.values(s)[0] );
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  const array = [{"a":{"name":"abc","age":2}},
  {"b":{"name":"xyz","age":3}},
  {"c":{"name":"pqr","age":4}}]

   array.map(item=>{
    return Object.keys(item).reduce((acc,key)=>{
      return item[key]
    },{})
  })
```

Comment: Nah, this one is ok, if you JSON.stringify the result, you got

"[{"name":"abc","age":2},{"name":"xyz","age":3},{"name":"pqr","age":4}]

Comment: I don't want the stringified JSON as I have to append other key values to it

Comment: @Erick: JSON *is* text. JSON != JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

And straight ahead dumb way as well:

```
src=[{"a":{"name":"abc","age":2}},
    {"b":{"name":"xyz","age":3}},
    {"c":{"name":"pqr","age":4}}]

result=[]
for arr in src:
    for d in arr:
        result.append(arr[d])
```

Comment: That appears to be Python, not JS.

Comment: Oh, yes, this is Python. I'm sorry, I didn't look careful at the question :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) iteration methods, like `map` or `reduce`. I prefer `reduce` for such kind of problems. `Array.prototype.reduce` takes the second parameter as a default value, so it's an empty array and for every iteration that array is concatenated with the value of an object e.g. `{ a: { name: "abc", age: 2 } }` will lead to adding `{ name: "abc", age: 2 }` to the resulted array.

```js
const input = [
      { a: { name: "abc", age: 2 } },
      { b: { name: "xyz", age: 3 } },
      { c: { name: "pqr", age: 4 } }
    ];

const output = input.reduce(
  (acc, entry) => acc.concat(Object.values(entry)),
  []
)

console.log(output)
```

Comment: acc is an object and concat won't work on that . @havenchyk
and it will only return the same array with the 0th index and the other 2 undefined

Comment: @Erick you can try to run code snippet to check the result :)

Comment: @Erick anyway, `Array.prorotype.reduce` takes the second parameter as a default value for `acc` and it's an empty array `[]`, hope it's clear now

Comment: @Isma definitely, but I presume that further readers know about `Array.prototype` methods, otherwise I need to include also different levels how code works up to `move eax, ebx`